# How we upload the csv file via custom module

Tags: magento, magento2

I need to create a custom module, which displays the custom menu in the admin backend and once click that menu, it will show the form of file input(accept csv file) and after clicking submit button, I need to read that file in my controller. Is that any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

First Create a module and  then -

1. add menu.xml file inside etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
>     <menu>
>         <add id="Vendor_Import::invoicegeneratemenu"
>              title="Import Events"
>              module="Vendor_Import"
>              sortOrder="105"
>              parent="Magento_Catalog::catalog"
>              action="vendor/import/index"
>              resource="Vendor_Import::invoicegenerate"
>         />
>     </menu>
> </config>
> ```

I have added this in Catalog Tab.

2. After Creating the menu Create a Controller for the same and also create a view XML file

and if want new menu then refer to this link -

https://bsscommerce.com/blog/create-admin-menu-in-magento-2/

Hope from Above link you have create a page in admin

```
<input name="csvfile" id="csvfile" title="file" value="" class="input-text" type="file" data-validate="{required:true}">

<div class="primary">
<button type="submit" class="action submit primary" id="upload" title="Save"><span><?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Upload')) ?></span></button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"],
        function($){
            $('#upload').on('click',function(){
                CheckData();
            });
            function CheckData(){
                var fd = new FormData();
                var files = $('#csvfile')[0].files;
                fd.append('csvfile', files[0]);
                fd.append('form_key',"<?php echo $block->getFormKey() ?>");

                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"controller_path_here",
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    processData:false,
                    contentType:false,
                    data: fd,
                }).done(function(data) {
                  //success code here  
                    }
                });
            }
        });
</script>
```

Now Create Controller and get the csv file in controller

Extend Controller with these -

```
class Controller_Name extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements \Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface
```

To get CSV data in execute function use below -

```
$file = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('csvfile');
```

Hope it helps!!